# sed-style replace letters with random letters, numbers with random numbers

Tags: bash, replace, sed, awk

I need to take a large file, with lines such as:

```
member: cn=user0001,ou=people
```

And replace all the usernames such that they still have letters in the same position and numbers in the same position, at random. So the output might be something like:

```
member: cn=kvud7405,ou=people
```

The usernames vary in length and format, but they're always bounded by a cn= and a comma.

Can anyone offer a solution with sed/awk/bash preferably, or failing that python might be an option (not sure which version).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F 'cn=|,' 'BEGIN {srand(); OFS = ""} {n = split($2, a, ""); for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {if (a[i] ~ /[[:digit:]]/) {new = new int(rand() * 10)} else {new = new sprintf("%c", int(rand() * 26 + 97))}}; $2 = "cn=" new ","; print}'
```

Broken out on multiple lines:

```
awk -F 'cn=|,' '
    BEGIN {
        srand(); 
        OFS = ""
    } 
    {
        n = split($2, a, ""); 
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (a[i] ~ /[[:digit:]]/) {
                new = new int(rand() * 10)
            }
            else {
                new = new sprintf("%c", int(rand() * 26 + 97))
            }
        }; 
        $2 = "cn=" new ","; 
        print
}'
```

It could easily be modified to handle uppercase alpha characters if needed.

**Edit:**

More robust:

```
awk 'BEGIN {srand()} {match($0, /cn=[^,]*,/); n = split(substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-4), a, ""); for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {if (a[i] ~ /[[:digit:]]/) {new = new int(rand() * 10)} else {new = new sprintf("%c", int(rand() * 26 + 97))}}; print substr($0, 1, RSTART+2) new substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH-1)}'
```

This version doesn't use `FS` so it works when there are additional fields.

Comment: Thanks. This looks great, but moving the goalposts slightly... I have some lines like this:

Comment: member: cn=kvud7405,ou=people,dc=uk

Comment: @rich: Yeah, I didn't feel very good about that version since it's not very robust. See my edit for a version that should be better.

Answer (score 5):

something like

```
sed -i 's/blah/blah?$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc "a-z0-9" | fold -w 6 | head -n 1)/g' /home/test.html
```

Comment: This is nice, but it seems much cleaner to do `< /dev/urandom tr -cd a-z0-9 | dd bs=6 count=1`

Answer (score 1):

A Bash solution:

```
letter=( a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z )
digit=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 )
while read line; do
  user=''
  line=${line#*=}                           # separate cn-value
  line=${line%,*}                           # separate cn-value
  for (( CNTR=0; CNTR<${#line}; CNTR+=1 )); do
    if [[ ${line:CNTR:1} =~ [[:alpha:]] ]] ; then
      user=$user${letter[RANDOM%26]}
    else
      user=$user${digit[RANDOM%10]}
    fi
  done
  echo  "member: cn=${user},ou=people"
done < "$infile" > "$tempfile"

mv "$tempfile" "$infile"                    # replace original file
```